# std::for_each function template

Tags: c++, foreach

`N4296::25.2.4 [alg.foreach]` provides requirements for the function `std::for_each`:

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function> Function
for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

> Requires: Function shall meet the requirements of MoveConstructible
>   (Table 20). [ Note: Function need not meet the requirements of
>   CopyConstructible (Table 21). —end note ]

OK, now what MoveConstructible is is the following:

```
Expression                    Post-condition
T u = rv;      u is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction
T(rv)          T(rv) is equivalent to the value of rv before the construction

rv’s state is unspecified [ Note:rv must still meet the requirements of the
library component that is using it. The operations listed in those requirements 
must work as specified whether rv has been moved from or not. —end note ]
```

There was no any mention about the type Function must have `operator ()` member function, but in fact it must. Does the Standard mention it explicitly?

Comment: I assume the standard says it's going to invoke `f(something)`.

Comment: @Hurkyl, It does say that it "applies `f`". I'm sure the formal definition of "apply" is somewhere in there, but I'd rather not spend a year looking.